# Why does Python have a magic "__class__" cell?

Tags: python, super

In Python, there are three ways for values to enter a scope: they are passed in as parameters, they are accessible from the enclosing scope, and finally the enclosing class and first parameter of the enclosing function are available to `super()`.  Why not expose this mechanism to the developer so that it can be extended for other cases?

Wouldn't it be cleaner to have a `__context__` `ChainMap` that is available everywhere, which exposes things?  By default, entering the definition of a class would expose the class itself in `__context__['__class__']` and entering a non-static, non-class member function would expose the first parameter as `__context__['self']`.  But, in general, we could do much more with a construct like

```
entercontext {'blah': 123}:
     f(__context__['blah'])
```

which would push the dict onto the ChainMap and pop it upon exiting the scope.

This could be then used to implement many other cases of settings such as numpy `set_printoptions`/`get_printoptions`, etc.  Instead of getting, setting, and restoring, you would just push them onto the context.

Comment: The `__class__` cell is only added when you use either `super()` or a local name `__class__ ` in a method; it is there to make `super()` boilerplate go away.

Comment: And as for entering contexts, that is what context managers are for; the `with` statement and `.__enter__()` and `.__exit__()` methods.

Comment: Interesting, but "why not" questions are generally best for a ML - pick any language, and there exists multiple "why not" questions that often come down to "because that's the way it is".

Comment: I do agree that the automatic closure for `__class__` flies in the face of the Python 'Better explicit than implicit' philosophy, but at the same time it heads off a common mistake to use `super(type(self), self)` or `super(self.__class__, self)` instead of using the class object the method is defined on. The closure at least lets you avoid that mistake by simply using `super()` and giving that function enough context to do its work.

Comment: But other than that, this question is better left to be discussed on the Python mailinglists (python-dev for the why, python-ideas for the context idea).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: How does `self` get passed to `super()`?  And, if it uses an extra cell, then why do we even pass `self` explicitly at all?

Comment: In Python 2, there was *no* option to call `super()` without arguments. You passed in the type *and* `self` to get bound methods; without `self` there is nothing to bind to. `super()` without arguments grabs the `__class__` closure and the *first* argument of the parent scope (which for methods, is always going to be `self`), to give you the same thing as `super(TypeObject, self)` would give; a context to find *bound methods* from parent classes.

Comment: @NeilG: You can still use the `super(TypeObject)` version, but then you get unbound methods instead. You'd have to pass in `self` as a first argument explicitly, not nearly as convenient.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yes, I understand all that :)  I'm just wondering how `super()` grabs the first argument.  Does the cell in which it's stored have a name?  Is it exposed within the method?

Comment: @NeilG: yes, `__class__`, and merely mentioning it in the method makes it accessible.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Sorry, I understand that the class is passed in `__class__`, in what cell is `self` stored?

Comment: It's not a cell, it doesn't need to be as it is a local.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: How does `super()` access it since function calls don't see locals, and anyway it wouldn't know what name you've given the first parameter?

Comment: You can see locals of functions up the stack, as the locals are still active. The names are irrelevant; locals for functions are kept in an array and referenced by index; the names are not needed once the compiler is done with the code, mostly. `super()` simply grabs the first local, which is always the first method argument.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thank you for explaining that.  Can I write my own function that grabs the first local by examining the stack?

Comment: You can; the [`inspect` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) can help, but study the [datamodel](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) too.